# How do I keep IOTA secure?

Tags: security, iota-cli

I am setting up a website where users buy and sell IOTA with USD. I've gotten some general safety tips about keeping your seed secure but I wanted to know what I could do to be safe from hackers, seeing that I will be holding my users' IOTA and can potentially be holding hundreds of thousands of dollars worth of IOTA. I'm also using the IOTA-cli wallet for generating addresses and sending funds.